# Command "geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc" throws Fatal Error

Tags: solidity, web3js, nethereum, c#

After deploying an private Ethereum blockchain with Azure Template "Proof of Work" we are not able to run the following command successfully.
"geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc" following image shows the specific error we are receiving.

[image]

The reason to run this script is because we are using nethereum web3 based c# code to execute the solidity contract. we are unable to unlock account and following is the error we are receiving during the execution of C# code.
[image]

Any Quick insights on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you might already have an instance of Geth running somewhere, which is already using the datadir. Does `ps faux | grep geth` give you any clues? Or failing that, `ps faux | grep <your_datadir>`

Answer (score 1):

This error means you already have a geth instance running, which could be the nethereum node instance sharing the same pid.

Try to kill it using ps or htop before running geth again